# Which object reference does GenericValue::AddMember return

Tags: rapidjson

The [`GenericValue`](http://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_generic_value.html) class of [RapidJSON](http://rapidjson.org) has an [`AddMember`](http://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_generic_value.html#ab018d734d189532b27943bc45776ba68) method, which returns a `GenericValue` reference:

```
 GenericValue& rapidjson::GenericValue< Encoding, Allocator >::AddMember(
    GenericValue< Encoding, Allocator > &name,
    GenericValue< Encoding, Allocator > &value,
    Allocator &allocator 
    )
```

The document says this returns

> The value itself for fluent API.

But **which** value (reference) does it return? The `value` given to the method (the value added)? Or the value to which the member has been added?

Comment: I am answering my own question [as is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 0):

The [source code](http://rapidjson.org/document_8h_source.html) has

```
 return *this;
```

Therefore the method returns the value *to which* the member has been added, not the value that *has been* added.

Hence, you can use the fluent API to add several members to one object:

```
 v.AddMember("foo", ...).AddMember("bar", ...);
```

Adds two new members, named "foo" and "bar", to `v`.